# Finding the coordinates of the corners of an aligned pole-centered spherical square

Tags: spherical-geometry, spherical-coordinates

Given a [spherical square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square#Non-Euclidean_geometry) of radius $1$, with edge midpoints at $(1, x, 0)$, $(1, x, \pi/2$), $(1, x, \pi)$ and $(1, x,3 \pi/2)$ (in the spherical coordinate system of (radial distance, polar angle, azimuthal angle)) what are the spherical coordinates of the corners of the square?

Comment: I have tried this using Wolfram Alpha, but it gives answers in terms of inverse trigonometric functions. I would expect that the points would be straightforward to express.

Comment: Are the corners of a spherical square allowed to be "co-linear" (i.e. lie along the same great circle)?  If so, $(1,x,\pi/4),(1,x,3\pi/4),(1,x,5\pi/4),(1,x,7\pi/4)$ should qualify.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom That would imply that $x = \pi/2$. I am looking for an answer for any acute $x$.

Comment: Just so we're clear here, $x$ is the polar (and not the azimuthal) angle, right?  If that is the case, then all of the midpoints lie along the great circle given by $$(1,x,t)\quad t\in[0,2\pi]$$  This parametrization gives us a great circle, regardless of the choice of $x$.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is. I'm going by the [top right Wikipedia definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system). The polar angle $x$ is the angle between the vector and the zenith, right? Constant $x$, $x < \pi/2$ should give a small circle.

Comment: Ah, I had my terminology mixed up.  I thought you were using the convention below. Sorry for the confusion.